# Joint distribution in layman's terms

Tags: joint-distribution, intuition

Can someone please explain to me in layman's terms what a joint distribution is? I do not understand it after seeing a word problem that pertained to joint distributions. Please provide the intuition and avoid mathematical equations.

Comment: For a discrete distribution of a random variable $X$, you can consider $\Pr(X=x)$ for different values of $x$.   For a discrete joint distribution of random variables $X$ and $Y$, you can consider $\Pr(X=x \text { and }Y=y)$ for different values of $x$ and $y$.  You need something more sophisticated for random variables with continuous distributions, but the intuitive idea is similar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a concrete example, suppose I toss a coin and roll a die one after the other. As you know, there is a probability distribution associated with the outcomes of both (discrete uniform distributions, i.e. every possible outcome is equally likely). I can use these to find e.g. P(coin lands heads) or P(I roll a six).

The joint probability distribution is just a distribution over *combinations* of these events. So it tells me about P(I roll a six and the coin lands heads), or P(the coin lands tails and I roll  a two).

As a continuous example, IQs are distributed normally with mean 100 and adult male heights are distributed normally with mean about $5' 10''$. The joint distribution is then a distribution over (height, IQ) *pairs*, so it tells you about the probability of having *both* a given height *and* a given IQ, rather than just one or the other. So armed with the joint distribution, I can now ask questions like 'what is the probability that a man off the street has an IQ between 90 and 110 *and* is between 5'9'' and 5'11' tall.'

In short, you make a new event, which is the combination of two events you already know about. The joint distribution tells you about the probability of the new event.

**Edit:**
As noted in the comments, when you are computing joint distributions, it's very important to think about whether the individual components are *independent*. Say we want to find the joint distribution over house prices and number of bedrooms in your neighbourhood. The result will still be a distribution over (house price, number of bedroom) pairs, just as above. However, you will need to explicitly account for the fact that these are *not independent* by using a conditional probability. This is what makes joint distributions really useful -- they account for the influence of one component on the other. 
Note also that in this example, the joint density is *mixed*, i.e. one component is continuous (house price) and one is discrete (number of bedrooms). We can still use it to ask, 'What is the probability that a house has 4 bedrooms and is worth between £400,000 and £500,000?'