# Is my intuition for the joint probability formula correct?

Tags: probability

my previous question was closed (due to confusing terms) so I am now making a hopefully clearer post. I have also seen this: [Joint distribution in layman's terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278057/joint-distribution-in-laymans-terms),

and as far as I can tell, the answer has a separate explanation for Joint Probability; I would like to know if my own understanding is reasonable.

I'd like to ask if I am understanding correctly the intuition behind the formula for P(A∩B), EDIT: given that A and B are events independent of each other

(Note: I use asterisks here to depict multiplication)

Firstly, the sample space, Ω, is the set of all possible outcomes. Thus, the probability of any outcome being in this space must be 1, as Ω encompasses all possibilities.

The probability of a specific event, A, is then some proportion of this sample space. Or, P(A) is the portion of events in Ω where A occurs.

Thus, if P(Ω) is the probability that an event occurs in Ω, and the value of this probability is 1, then, P(Ω) * P(A) = 1 * P(A) = P(A)

I think it might look redundant, but I meant to convey that because the event being in the sample space Ω must happen, then P(A) can only be some fraction of this event.

Now, since the probability P(A∩B) is being discussed, A and B must occur simultaneously to represent (A∩B). And because both have to occur, we can allow either of these events to be analogous to the sample space Ω in the previous example.

Consider if B takes the place of the sample space from the previous example. In this sense, what I'm trying to say is that, conceptually, in the space of events where B occurs, P(A∩B) is the portion of this space where A also occurs.

But, mathematically, we can use P(B) as the 'sample space' (because in this example, P(A∩B) is being discussed, so both events have to happen), then P(A∩B) is also just the portion of this 'new sample space'. So:

P(A∩B) = P(B) * P(A)

I hope I'm not being confusing with trying to treat either P(B) or P(A) as the sample space, but in the end, what I wanted to communicate with that is that we can assume either event 'happens', then we only need the proportion of it where the other event also occurs, which is how the joint probability formula is arrived at. Of course, in my second example A and B can be conceptually switched.

Please let me know if I am still being unclear, of I have made jumps in my logic/reasoning.

Comment: I made it through all this text without finding a question!  What are you trying to ask?